# How to add validation in <select> tag using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
 pushData=[];
 //+ button when clicked
 function myFunction() {
     var custOfficeId=document.getElementById('customOfficeId').value;
     var custOfficeName=$("#customOfficeId option:selected").text();
     var fromDate=document.getElementById('fromDate').value;
     var toDate=document.getElementById('toDate').value;
     var consignmentNo=document.getElementById('consignmentNo').value;
     var selectionName="aa";
     var selectionId=1;
     var selecOff={custOfficeId,custOfficeName,fromDate,toDate,consignmentNo,selectionId,selectionName}; 
     console.log(selecOff);
     pushData.push(selecOff);
     if(!fromDate){
      $("#fromDateError").html('From Date can not be left blank');
      /* alert("From Date is null"); */
     }
      if (!toDate){
      $("#toDateError").html('To Date can not be left blank');
      /* alert("To Date is null"); */
     }
     if(!consignmentNo){
      $("#consignmentNoError").html('Consignment No can not be left blank');
     }
     if(!fromDate && !toDate &&  !consignmentNo){
      alert("herte");
      $("#fromDateError").html('From Date can not be left blank');
      $("#toDateError").html('To Date can not be left blank');
      $("#consignmentNoError").html('Consignment No can not be left blank');
     }
     populateSelectionCustomTable();
    
 }
 
 function populateSelectionCustomTable(){

  $("#tempTable tbody").html("");
  for (var i = 0; i < pushData.length; i++) {
   var r = pushData[i];
   $("#tempTable tbody")
     .append(
       "<tr>" 
         + "<td>"
         + r.custOfficeName
         + "</td><td>"
         + r.fromDate
         + "</td><td>"
         + r.toDate
         + "</td>"
         + "<td>"
         + r.consignmentNo
         + "</td>"
         + "<td>"
         + r.selectionName
         + "</td>"
         + "<td>"
         +"<input id='filter"+i+"' value='Delete' type='button' alt='Delete"
         + i
         + "' class='deleteIcon'/>"
         + "</td></tr></tbody>");
  }

 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/theme/css/nepali.datepicker.v2.2.min.css' />
      <link href="/theme/fonts/preeti/stylesheet.css"
         rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="form-group row">
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <label>Custom Office</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>From Date</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <label>To Date</label>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">Consignment No</div>
         <div class="col-md-4">
            <select class="form-control" id="customOfficeId" required
               name="customOfficeId" >
               <option value="" disabled selected>Choose</option>
               <option value=1>BIRATNAGAR BHANSAR</option>
               <option value=2>BHAIRAWA BHANSAR</option>
            </select>
            <span id="selectError" style="color:red;font-weight:bold"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control nepali-calendar ndp-nepali-calendar" id="fromDate" 
               onfocus="showNdpCalendarBox('fromDate')" name="fromDate" required/>
            <span id="fromDateError" style="color:red;font-weight:bold"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control nepali-calendar ndp-nepali-calendar" id="toDate"
               name="toDate"  onfocus="showNdpCalendarBox('toDate')" required />
            <span id="toDateError" style="color:red;font-weight:bold"></span>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="consignmentNo"
               required name="consignmentNo">
            <span id="consignmentNoError" style="color:red;font-weight:bold"></span>
         </div>
         <!-- </form> -->
         <div class="col-md-1">
            <button onclick="myFunction()">+</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <table class="table table-bodered" id="tempTable">
         <thead>
            <th>Custom Office</th>
            <th>From Date</th>
            <th>To Date</th>
            <th>Consignment No</th>
            <th>Selection Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </body>
```

I have added the valdation message for the input fields but I am stuck how to add validation for select tag.
[image]

"Choose" is the default value shown on  when page is loaded at first.But when i press "+" button just that choose value is going on table downward,since it is not any relevant data to move to table.How can i validate for the  tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't this work?

```
if (!custOfficeId) {
    $("#selectError").html('Custom office can not be left blank');
}
```

you don't need the `if(!fromDate && !toDate &&  !consignmentNo){ ... }` section - just add a `valid` flag that's initialized to `true` and set to `false` if any of the validations fail. Invoke `populateSelectionCustomTable` only when `valid` is true, i.e.

```
let valid = true;
if (!custOfficeId) {
    $("#selectError").html('Custom office can not be left blank');
    valid = false;
}
if (!fromDate) {
    $("#fromDateError").html('From Date can not be left blank');
    valid = false;
}
if (!toDate) {
    $("#toDateError").html('To Date can not be left blank');
    valid = false;
}
if (!consignmentNo) {
    $("#consignmentNoError").html('Consignment No can not be left blank');
    valid = false;
}
if (valid) {
    populateSelectionCustomTable();
}
```